# Converting matrix to an array in python

Tags: python

I have an array of array in python. What is the best way to convert it to an array in python?
for example:

```
m = [[1,2],[3,4]]
# convert to [1,2,3,4]
```

I am new in python, so I dont know any solution of it better than writing a loop. Please help.

Comment: This is called flattening a nested list. These keywords should help in your research.

Comment: First thing you should do is get in terms with the python terminology. It will make it easier for you to look for code samples and ask questions. There are no arrays in python (unless you use some 3rd paty module such as numpy), there are lists.

Comment: @StoryTeller: There are in fact no built-in arrays in Python. However, arrays are available through the standard array module (http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).

Comment: The type you are using are not arrays but lists. As said by EOL, *arrays are available through the [standard array](http://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) module*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `itertools.chain` or `list comprehension`:

```
from itertools import chain

list(chain(*m))  # shortest
# or:
list(chain.from_iterable(m)) # more efficient
```

---

For smaller lists `comprehension` is faster, for longer ones `chain.from_iterable` is more suitable.

```
[item for subl in m for item in subl]
```

For understanding the nested comprehension, you can split it across multiple lines and compare it to a regular for loop:

```
[item                         #result = []
    for subl in m             #for subl in m:  
        for item in subl]     #    for item in subl:
                              #        result.append(item)
```

Comment: I feel obligated to ask this regarding the third method. Uh!? Please either use more meaningful names or provide a step by step explanation.

Comment: Why 2nd method is preferred over 3rd one?

Comment: @MoazzamKhan -- I actually meant, that using `chain.from_iterable` should be used over the first option, using the list comprehension is fine.

Comment: @StoryTeller -- added some explanation :)

Comment: Thanks to all of you, it was really helpful.